# how to create csv files in row wise with header using php

Tags: php, csv

While downloading the csv file it displaying the values in column wise.
here is the code:

```
$id=1;
getPackage($certificate_id);
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
function getPackage($id){
$q_pack="select p.filename,p.version from cert c join packages p on c.package_id=p.id left join documents dt on p.id=dt.package_id left join documents doc on doc.id=d.document_id where c.certificate_id=$id";
$res_pack = db_query($q_pack);
if ($res_pack) {
while ($pack_row = db_fetch_object($res_pack)){
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $pack_row as $line ) {
$val = explode(",", $line);
fputcsv($fp, $val);}
fclose($fp);}}
```

And also need to add add the header in row wise.
Please find the screenshot how the csv file need to be[image: Csv file]

Comment: what do you want in header

Comment: @NavnitMishra header as Filename & Version

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of way, a simple way could be inject the value from the query as example:

```
$q_pack="select 'filename', 'version' from dual union select p.filename,p.version from cert c join packages p on c.package_id=p.id left join documents dt on p.id=dt.package_id left join documents doc on doc.id=d.document_id where c.certificate_id=$id";
```

Otherwise some other trick based on the first interaction of the extraction

Comment: In csv file each row it getting the error like <div class='database-error'> & ******** SQL error ********, The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns</div><!--.

Comment: @Priya very strange: the first select extract two field same as the second (the constraint of the union is that the queries need to extract the same number of argument)